How to tell if any of the tasks in the DAG has failed?
In a DAG, how can I tell if any of the tasks in the DAG has failed?
Suppose I have a DAG that looks like this (simplified version):

Any of the DAGs in the middle (201, 202) may fail. But when they fail, the FINAL node is not executed.
Now of course I could check all of the intermediary tasks (201, 202), but that quickly becomes unwieldy as I add more and more tasks. So ideally I would check for a failure of ANY task in a DAG.
My original idea was to check the final task:
SELECT NAME, STATE, ERROR_CODE, ERROR_MESSAGE, QUERY_START_TIME, COMPLETED_TIME
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TASK_HISTORY())
WHERE NAME = 'ANRUFGRUENDE_FINAL_TSK'
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY COMPLETED_TIME DESC NULLS LAST) = 1 -- only show latest run;

but it never executes if an upstream task fails, so that's not feasible. I guess I could take the absence of an expected FINAL task run as an indicator that an upstream task has failed, but I would rather have a direct signal instead.
What is the best way to approach this?

And yes, I know that "Airflow" is the real answer to my problem, but let's assume for a minute that we want to find a solution using Snowflake tasks only.

Checking status using COMPLETE_TASK_GRAPHS SELECT * FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COMPLETE_TASK_GRAPHS(ROOT_TASK_NAME=>'<name>'));  Also: Enabling error notifications for tasks

Oh, sweet, didn't know about COMPLETE_TASK_GRAPHS! Why don't you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

COMPLETE_TASK_GRAPHS can be used to check the status of tasks execution:

Returns the status of a completed graph run. The function returns details for runs that executed successfully, failed, or were cancelled in the past 60 minutes

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COMPLETE_TASK_GRAPHS(ROOT_TASK_NAME=>'<name>'));


COMPLETE_TASK_GRAPHS view

Latency for the view may be up to 45 minutes.

SELECT *
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.COMPLETE_TASK_GRAPHS;


Caveat: only shows task graph runs for the last 60 minutes (src: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/complete_task_graphs)

@Sebastian  For full history you normally use ACCOUNT_USAGE view which has latency.

Yeah but TASK_HISTORY has no info on the Task Graph, so that doesn't help me with my original problem.

@Sebastian "Yeah but TASK_HISTORY has no info on the Task Graph" I am referring to SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.COMPLETE_TASK_GRAPHS view

That's awesome, thanks for the clarification!

So to get it all in one:
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (
SELECT ROOT_TASK_NAME, DATABASE_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, STATE, SCHEDULED_TIME, COMPLETED_TIME
FROM TABLE(information_schema.complete_task_graphs())
UNION ALL
SELECT ROOT_TASK_NAME, DATABASE_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, STATE, SCHEDULED_TIME, COMPLETED_TIME
FROM snowflake.account_usage.complete_task_graphs
)
ORDER BY scheduled_time DESC;
